# Error while predicting classes of an trained DNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, prediction

I used the following program to predict classes for my image.

> ```
> from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
>
> x = load_img("8-SignLanguageMNIST/test1.jpg", target_size = (28, 28))
>
> x = img_to_array(x)
>
> x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)
>
> x = np.vstack([x])
>
> classes = model.predict(x)
> print(classes[0])
> ```

The Images I used for training are of shape (28, 28, 1).

Here I am uploading an RGB image which is of shape (28, 28, 3), I tried converting that image to grayscale and then predicting but kept getting the following error.

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 28, 28, 3]
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, and help me out with that.

Comment: where is the conversion to gray scale?

Comment: Actually I did that manually using Photoshop.

Comment: your image is still rgb also after loading (3 channels). try with load_img(path, color_mode='grayscale') as u can see here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to apply a [conversion to grayscale](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img) like below:

```
load_img(path, color_mode='grayscale')
```